# New list column is not displaying in dropdown list when creating a lookup column

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, lookup-column

I have an existing list called Employees and I have added a new column "Company". I would like to create a lookup column using Company but Company is not displaying as an option in the dropdown list or additional fields. The Employee content type does have Company listed. Any ideas why Company is not being listed when creating a lookup column?

Answer (score 0):

Only this types can be displayed as additional fields:

- Single line of text
- Number
- Date
- Date and Time
- Calculeted single line of text
- External data: OnHandQuantity
  More info [here](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.ru/2012/01/sharepoint-not-all-column-types-can-be.html)